# Moving certain files from subdirectories in Python

Tags: python, shutil, file-move

I have a large folder with lots of subfolders, each of which contains one to several files.
I'd like to move some of these files based on their filename. I have a list containing the filenames of the files I want to move, so basically I would like to check for every file in the mither directory if it's name's on the list and if so - move it to the new directory.

I wrote the following script, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea how to fix it, or a better suggestion for a script that would perform the desired function?

```
import os
import shutil

curr_fold = "/Users/ruthersh/Alice/Bacterial_seqs/FAA"
dest = "/Users/ruthersh/Alice/Bacterial_seqs/Plasmids"

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(curr_fold):
    for filename in files:
        if (filename[:9]) in NCS:
            src = os.path.realpath(filename)
            shutil.move(src, dest)
```

Comment: What do you mean *"doesn't work"*? Errors (provide full traceback)? What is `NCS`?

Answer (score 1):

From Python Standard Library documentation on `os.walk` : *Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name)*. So you should have

```
src = os.join(dirname, filename)
```

If something goes wrong, please add some print statements to verify the values of src, and eventually dest to see what you **really** ask to `shutils`.